# What happens when the raw pointer from shared_ptr get() is deleted?

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, undefined-behavior, delete-operator

I wrote some code like this:

```
shared_ptr<int> r = make_shared<int>();
int *ar = r.get();

delete ar; // report double free or corruption
// still some code
```

When the code ran up to `delete ar;`, the program crashed, and reported​ "double free or corruption",  I'm confused why double free? The "r" is still in the scope, and not popped-off from stack. Do the delete operator do something magic?? Does it know the raw pointer is handled by a smart pointer currently? and then counter in "r" be decremented to zero automatically? 
I know the operations is not recommended， but I want to know why?

Comment: To be clear: you know the code isn't correct but can't understand the specific symptoms of that incorrect code that has undefined behavior, right?

Comment: The error message is "double free or corruption" and you seem to be assuming it's a double free. But it's not. It's corruption. There is no requirement that `get()` return a pointer that was created by `new`. In the case of `make_shared`, the standard recommends that the control block and the contained object be merged into a single larger allocation. In that case, the pointer returned by `get()` is not deletable.

Answer (score 2):

You are deleting a pointer that didn't come from `new`, so you have undefined behavior (anything can happen).

From cppreference on [delete](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete):

> For the first (non-array) form, expression must be a pointer to an object type or a class type contextually implicitly convertible to such pointer, and its value must be either null or pointer to a non-array object created by a new-expression, or a pointer to a base subobject of a non-array object created by a new-expression. If expression is anything else, including if it is a pointer obtained by the array form of new-expression, the behavior is undefined.

If the allocation is done by `new`, we can be sure that the pointer we have is something we can use `delete` on. But in the case of `shared_ptr.get()`, we cannot be sure if we can use `delete` because it might not be the actual pointer returned by `new`.

Comment: You missed the important part: OP assumes that the pointer came from `new`, because after all, `shared_ptr` deletes the shared object upon final destruction, so "clearly" the shared object was created by `new` (so that `shared_ptr` can delete it). But you are saying that it wasn't created by `new`. How can that be?

Comment: @RaymondChen: If the allocation is done by `new`, we can be sure that the pointer we have is something we can use `delete` on. But in the case of shared_ptr.get(), we cannot be sure if we can use `delete` because it might not be the actual pointer returned by `new`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Right, and that's the important point. When you use `make_shared`, you cannot be sure if the underlying object was created by `new`.

Answer (score 0):

```
shared_ptr<int> r = make_shared<int>();
```

There is no guarantee that this will call `new int` (which isn't strictly observable by the user anyway) or more generally `new T` (which is observable with a user defined, class specific `operator new`); in practice, it won't (there is no guarantee that it won't).

The discussion that follows isn't just about `shared_ptr`, but about "smart pointers" with **ownership** semantics. For any owning smart pointer *smart_owning*:

The primary motivation for *make_owning* instead of `smart_owning<T>(new T)` is to avoid having a memory allocation without owner at any time; that was essential in C++ when order of evaluation of expressions didn't provide the guarantee that evaluation of the sub-expressions in the argument list was immediately before call of that function; historically in C++:

```
f (smart_owning<T>(new T), smart_owning<U>(new U));
```

could be evaluated as:

```
T *temp1 = new T;
U *temp2 = new U;
auto &&temp3 = smart_owning<T>(temp1);
auto &&temp4 = smart_owning<U>(temp2);
```

This way `temp1` and `temp2` are not managed by any owning object for a non trivial time:

- obviously `new U` can throw an exception
- constructing an owning smart pointer usually requires the allocation of (small) ressources and can throw

So either `temp1` or `temp2` could be leaked (but not both) if an exception was thrown, which was the exact problem we were trying to avoid in the first place. This means composite expressions involving construction of owning smart pointers was a bad idea; this is fine:

```
auto &&temp_t = smart_owning<T>(new T);
auto &&temp_u = smart_owning<U>(new U);
f (temp_t, temp_u);
```

Usually expression involving as many sub-expression with function calls as `f (smart_owning<T>(new T), smart_owning<U>(new U))` are considered reasonable (it's a pretty simple expression in term of number of sub-expressions). Disallowing such expressions is quite annoying and very difficult to justify.

[This is one reason, and in my opinion the most compelling reason, why the non determinism of the order of evaluation was removed by the C++ standardisation committee so that such code is not safe. (This was an issue not just for memory allocated, but for any managed allocation, like file descriptors, database handles...)]

Because code frequently needed to do things such as `smart_owning<T>(allocate_T())` in sub-expressions, and because telling programmers to decompose moderately complex expressions involving allocation in many simple lines wasn't appealing (more lines of code doesn't mean easier to read), the library writers provided a simple fix: a function to do the creation of an object with dynamic lifetime and the creation of its owning object together. That solved the order of evaluation problem (but was complicated at first because it needed perfect forwarding of the arguments of the constructor).

Giving two tasks to a function (allocate an instance of `T` and a instance of `smart_owning`) gives the freedom to do an interesting optimization: you can avoid one dynamic allocation by putting both the managed object and its owner next to each others.

But once again, that was *not* the primary purpose of functions like `make_shared`.

Because exclusive ownership smart pointers *by definition* don't need to keep a reference count, and by definition don't need to share the data needed for the deleter either between instances, and so can keep that data in the "smart pointer"(*), no additional allocation is needed for the construction of `unique_ptr`; yet a `make_unique` function template was added, to avoid the dangling pointer issue, not to optimize a non-thing (an allocation that isn't done in the fist place).

(*) which BTW means unique owner "smart pointers" do *not* have *pointer* semantic, as pointer semantic implies that you can makes copies of the "pointer", and you can't have two copies of a unique owner pointing to the same instance; "smart pointers" were never pointers anyway, the term is misleading.

**Summary:**

`make_shared<T>` does an *optional* optimization where **there is no separate dynamic memory allocation for `T`**: there is no `operator new(sizeof (T))`. There is obviously still the creation of an instance with dynamic lifetime with another `operator new`: **placement new**.

If you replace the explicit memory deallocation with an explicit destruction and add a pause immediately after that point:

```
class C { 
public:
  ~C();
};
shared_ptr<C> r = make_shared<C>();
C *ar = r.get();
ar->~C();
pause(); // stops the program forever
```

The program will probably run fine; *it is still illogical, indefensible, incorrect to explicitly destroy an object managed by a smart pointer*. It isn't "your" resource. If `pause()` could exit with an exception, the owning smart pointer would try to destroy the managed object which doesn't even exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It of course depends on how library implements make_shared, however most probable implementation is that:

std::make_shared allocates one block for two things:

- shared pointer control block
- contained object

std::make_shared() will invoke memory allocator once and then it will call placement new twice to initialize (call constructors) of mentioned two things.

```
|           block requested from allocator          |
| shared_ptr control block |         X object       |
#1                         #2                       #3
```

That means that memory allocator has provided one big block, which address is #1.
Shared pointer then uses it for control block (#1) and actual contained object (#2).
When you invoke delete with actual object kept by shred_ptr ( .get() ) you call delete(#2).
Because #2 is not known by allocator you get an corruption error.

Answer (score -2):

<strike>See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). I quot:</strike>

> std::shared_ptr is a smart pointer that retains shared ownership of an object through a pointer. Several shared_ptr objects may own the same object. The object is destroyed and its memory deallocated when either of the following happens:
>
> - the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object is destroyed;
> - the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object is assigned another pointer via operator= or reset().
>
> The object is destroyed using delete-expression or a custom deleter that is supplied to shared_ptr during construction.

So the pointer is deleted by `shared_ptr`. You're not suppose to delete the stored pointer yourself

**UPDATE:**

I didn't realize that there were more statements and the pointer was not out of scope, I'm sorry.

I was reading more and the standard doesn't say much about the behavior of `get()` but [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get) is a note, I quote:

> A shared_ptr may share ownership of an object while storing a pointer to another object. get() returns the stored pointer, not the managed pointer.

So it looks that it is allowed that the pointer returned by `get()` is not necessarily the same pointer allocated by the `shared_ptr` (presumably using `new`). So `delete` that pointer is undefined behavior. I will be looking a little more into the details.

**UPDATE 2:**

The standard says at § 20.7.2.2.6 (about `make_shared`):

> 6 Remarks: Implementations are encouraged, but not required, to perform no more than one memory allocation. [ Note: This provides efficiency equivalent to an intrusive smart pointer. — end note ]
>
> 7 [ Note: These functions will typically allocate more memory than sizeof(T) to allow for internal bookkeeping structures such as the reference counts. — end note ]

So an specific implementation of `make_shared` *could* allocate a single chunk of memory (or more) and use part of that memory to initialize the *stored pointer* (but maybe not all the memory allocated). `get()` must return a pointer to the stored object, but there is no requirement by the standard, as previously said, that the pointer returned by `get()` has to be the one allocated by `new`. So `delete` that pointer *is* undefined behavior, you got a signal raised but anything can happen.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the problem occurs before `r` goes out of scope (before the owning object is deleted). The OP seems well aware that what they're doing is illegal, it just shouldn't have caused a problem *yet*.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I am editing my answer to reflect what you pointed. I read quickly and didn't realize `r` was not out of scoped.